# How to stream an mp4 filesrc to a rtspsink using GStreamer 0.10

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-0.10

I have to use gstreamer 0.10 and try to stream a mp4 file.

For that I tried

gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=./test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! video/x-h264,mapping=/stream ! udpsink rtsp://192.168.192.100:12345/test

and received a warning:
WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "h264parse"

How can I stream the file as rtsp stream?

Comment: h264parse is part of gst-plugins-bad1.0 make sure you have installed it. To stream an mp4 file refer this link https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-mp4.c

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

sudo apt-get install libgstrtspserver-1.0 libgstreamer1.0-dev

wget https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c

gcc test-launch.c -o test-launch $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-rtsp-server-1.0)

./test-launch "filesrc location=`<full-path-to-your-mp4-video-file`> ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96"

At the client machine, to test, I run ffplay or VLC Player:

ffplay rtsp://`<your-server-ip`>:8554/test

Answer (score 1):

To get h264parse plugin, run
"sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad"

Pipelines

Sender

gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= ~/file.mp4 ! qtdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 ! udpsink host=ip_address_to_stream_to port=9999 -v

Receiver

gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc  port=9999 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, payload=(int)96, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtph264depay ! identity silent=0 ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! ximagesink